# Code explanation about interface and callback function

Tags: go

```
package lru

import "container/list"

// Cache is a LRU cache. It is not safe for concurrent access.
type Cache struct {
    maxBytes int64
    nbytes   int64
    ll       *list.List
    cache    map[string]*list.Element
    // optional and executed when an entry is purged.
    OnEvicted func(key string, value Value)
}

type entry struct {
    key   string
    value Value
}

// Value use Len to count how many bytes it takes
type Value interface {
    Len() int
}

// New is the Constructor of Cache
func New(maxBytes int64, onEvicted func(string, Value)) *Cache {
    return &Cache{
        maxBytes:  maxBytes,
        ll:        list.New(),
        cache:     make(map[string]*list.Element),
        OnEvicted: onEvicted,
    }
}

// RemoveOldest removes the oldest item
func (c *Cache) RemoveOldest() {
    ele := c.ll.Back()
    if ele != nil {
        c.ll.Remove(ele)
        kv := ele.Value.(*entry)
        delete(c.cache, kv.key)
        c.nbytes -= int64(len(kv.key)) + int64(kv.value.Len())
        if c.OnEvicted != nil {
            c.OnEvicted(kv.key, kv.value)
        }
    }
}

// Add adds a value to the cache.
func (c *Cache) Add(key string, value Value) {
    if ele, ok := c.cache[key]; ok {
        c.ll.MoveToFront(ele)
        kv := ele.Value.(*entry)
        c.nbytes += int64(value.Len()) - int64(kv.value.Len())
        kv.value = value
    } else {
        ele := c.ll.PushFront(&entry{key, value})
        c.cache[key] = ele
        c.nbytes += int64(len(key)) + int64(value.Len())
    }
    for c.maxBytes != 0 && c.maxBytes < c.nbytes {
        c.RemoveOldest()
    }
}
```

I am pretty new to golang. Here is a snippet of code of lru cache implementation.
I have a few questions:

1. the entry struct has a field of Value, which I assume is an empty interface. Possibly a node value in list.Element? I check the implemtation of double linked list of go.

```
type Element struct {
    Value interface{}
}
```

if the assumption is correct, how could entry declare a field which type is inside another struct (the Element struct)

2. when you try to get the Value of node, `kv := ele.Value.(*entry)` why use type assertion, does `kv := ele.Value` achieve the same result?
3. what does OnEvicted() do? Can function be implemented within struct? Detailed explaination please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ... has field of value that need to implement Value interface... (value interface can have Len() method that return int. )
2. `kv := ele.Value` is making `kv` of type `interface{}`, `kv := ele.Value.(*entry)` is making `kv` of type `*entry`, otehrwise using `kv.key` in delete wouldn't be possible, as interface{} have no idea that I have `key` field.
3. if `OnEvicted` provided, it will be called with key, and Value (this can be logging record, or maybe something else useful)